# Css. Помогите  с задачей.

Tags: css

Хтмл код:

```
﻿

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Главная</title>
    <!-- Style -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>

<p>текст</p>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

</body>
</html>

Цсс код:

```
 body {
    background: url("../img/bg.png") repeat;
}
```

НЕ задает фон боди. Все правельно подключил ... В чем ошибка? Что может быть?

Comment: background: url("../img/bg.png") 0 0 repeat;
Проверьте права на файл, что показывает консоль?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Если не работает, то либо стили не подключаются, либо рисунок не найден. Тогда:

Проверьте:

```
background-color: #f00;
```

если фон стал красным -> стили подключаются верно, рисунок не найден. Если ничего не изменилось то не подключается CSS.